# $\int_a^\infty f(x)\sin(e^x)\text{d}x$ conditionally convergent

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

> Let $f$ be a bounded $C^1$ function on $[a,\infty)$ such that
>   $\int_a^\infty f$ diverges. Assume there is $t>a$ s.t $f'(x)<f(x)$ on
>   $[t,\infty)$. prove $\int_a^\infty f(x)\sin(e^x)\text{d}x$ is 
>   conditionally convergent.

I couldn't really get anything done. It seems like a Dirichlet test result but $f$ doesn't have to approach $0$ at infinity, nor it is monotonic. The given property $f'<f$ seems related to the $e^x$ in the integral but I can't connect the two. The fact that  $\int_a^\infty f$ diverges seems to hint some sort of comparision test, but that too does not yield anything as $\underbrace{f(x)\sin(e^x)}_\text{????}\leq \underbrace{f(x)}_\text{integral will diverge}$

Comment: I'd write $f(x) \sin (e^x)$ as $\bigl( f(x)e^{-x}\bigr) e^x\sin (e^x)$ [or substitute $u = e^x$] and try an integration by parts.

Comment: You just get more complicated terms, like $\int_a^\infty (f'(x)-f(x))e^{-x}\sin(e^x)\text{d}x$ (Which is related to $f'<f$ but doesn't yield anything)

Answer (score 3):

Let $\text{Si}(z)=\int_{0}^{z}\frac{\sin u}{u}\,du$. By integration by parts we have:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{a}^{M}\sin(e^x)\,f(x)\,dx &=& \int_{e^a}^{e^M}\frac{\sin u}{u}\,f(\log u)\,du\\&\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}&\left[\text{Si}(u)\,f(\log u)\right]_{e^a}^{e^M}-\int_{e^a}^{e^M}\frac{\text{Si}(u)}{u}\,f'(\log u)\,du\end{eqnarray*} $$
where $\text{Si}(u)\to\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $u\to +\infty$. In particular there is some $b\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\text{Si}(u)\in\left[\frac{3}{2},2\right]$ for any $u\geq b$. Let $c=\max(e^a,b)$. Disregarding what happens on the bounded interval $[e^a,c]$, for any $M$ such that $e^M\geq c$ it is simple to bound both $[\text{Si}(u)\,f(\log u)]_{c}^{e^M}$ and
$$ \int_{c}^{e^M}\frac{\text{Si}(u)}{u}\,f'(u)\,du$$
(by the [mean value theorem for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)) with an absolute constant, only depending on $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^+}\left|f(x)\right|$ and $b$. This proves that $\int_{a}^{M}\sin(e^x)\,f(x)\,dx$ is uniformly bounded with respect to $M$. In order to finish the proof, it is enough to show that
$$ \lim_{M\to +\infty}\int_{a}^{M}e^{-x} f(x)\cdot \underbrace{e^x \sin(e^x)}_{\text{bounded primitive}}\,dx $$
exists. Invoking [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), it is enough to show that $f(x)e^{-x}$ is decreasing towards zero from some point on. Can you finish the proof by yourself, noting that $f'(x)<f(x)$ for any $x\geq t$ is among the assumptions? Futher hint: consider the derivative of $f(x)e^{-x}$ and the fact that $f$ is bounded.

**Side note**: it looks to me that the assumption about the unbounded-ness of $\int f$ never comes into play.

Comment: Is this good timing to say we were never introduced to $\text{Si}$?

Comment: The second part however really helped!

Comment: @Theorem: everything you need to know about $\text{Si}$ is that it is a differentiable, positive and bounded function over $\mathbb{R}^+$, converging to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as its parameter goes to $+\infty$. Anyway, here it is the Sine Integral function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html